# Orthonormal set for the set of compactly supported functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, laplacian, eigenfunctions

How to find an orthonormal set in the space of compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$? Moreover, for the operator $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}$, what are the eigenfunctions in the space of compactly supported smooth functions on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I realize you wrote "an orthonormal _set_" rather than "basis", but finding just an orthonormal set is too easy: take one smooth compactly supported function, and normalize it. Voilà, an orthonormal set with 1 element. Throw in its translates with disjoint supports to get an infinite orthonormal set.

Answer (score 3):

#### Orthonormal basis in the space of compactly supported smooth functions

One has to define an inner product first; I assume you mean the $L^2$ inner product, $\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} fg$. Since normalizing the basis vectors is easy, let's focus on *orthogonal* bases.

The [Daubechies wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daubechies_wavelet) provides an orthogonal basis for $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ which consists of compactly supported functions of class $C^{k}$, where $k$ can be made arbitrarily large (at the cost of increasing the complexity of the wavelet). See sections 1.3 and 1.4 of [these lecture notes](http://www2.isye.gatech.edu/~brani/isyebayes/bank/handout20.pdf).

There [does not exist](http://cas.ensmp.fr/~chaplais/Wavetour_presentation/ondelettes/Properties_of_Orth_Wave.html) a $C^\infty$-smooth compactly supported orthogonal wavelet. Thus, the typical options for an explicit orthogonal basis in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ consist of the following.

- Give up compact support and use [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions) or [Meyer wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meyer_wavelet).
- Downgrade from infinite smoothness to $C^k$ smoothness and use the Daubechies wavelet or its relatives.
- Give up all smoothness (and even continuity) and use the much simpler [Haar wavelet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_wavelet) or the functions $f_{m,n}(t) = \exp(2\pi i n t)\chi_{[m,m+1]}$.

In principle, an orthonormal basis consisting of $C^\infty$ smooth  compactly supported functions can be constructed by applying the Gram-Schmidt process to some complete set of such functions (like monomials multiplied by the shifts of a smooth bump function). But the computation would be intractable, and the resulting basis not even remotely explicit.

#### Smooth compactly supported eigenfunctions of $d^2/dx^2$

There are none. On the Fourier transform side, applying $d^2/dx^2$ amounts to multiplying by $-\xi^2$. So the Fourier transform of an eigenfunction has to be supported on the set $\{\pm \sqrt{-\lambda}\}$, which means the eigenfunction is of the form $A\cos \sqrt{-\lambda} x+B\sin \sqrt{-\lambda} x$. Not compactly supported, obviously.

Comment: thanks a lot for the explanation, yes I was looking for a basis!!